# How to access the elements within an <IFRAME>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to access the elements within an  in WebBrowser in C#.NET?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  If you're just trying to parse some html, perhaps WebClient or HttpRequest will meet your needs

Comment: @chad I think he is talking about Winforms

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idName").SetAttribute("value") = "ddddd" ;
var stuff=webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idName").GetAttribute("attribute");
```

it works for me when I need to get/set control data and get any html element value

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't.  C# and .NET are typically used in frameworks like ASP.NET to produce the content that is consumed by the browser.  This happens on the **server-side**.

If .NET is installed on the client, then you can [host a Windows Forms control in an HTML document in Internet Explorer](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030610.htm) but this is very, very non-standard, and I'd advise **heavily** against doing so.

Comment: @casper I think he is talking about the WebBrowser control for Winforms

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you can access the controls inside the webbroswer control using the following code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("controlId").
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Additionally this [discussion in daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread250107.html) might be of some interest to you.

Comment: What did you mean by it did not help? How did it not help you? I have a similar application and it works for me. Its not an iframe though