# Login to kingdoms.com programmatically with c# web browser (textboxes and button in iframe)

Tags: c#, html, authentication, webbrowser-control, bots

I want to login to kingdoms.com with a web browser. But the login screen is in an iframe tag, so I can't reach the email, password textboxes and login button. please help me.

```
HtmlWindowCollection iframes = wb.Document.Window.Frames;

HtmlWindow iframe = wb.Document.Window.Frames[2];

HtmlElement element = iframe.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299091/how-to-access-the-elements-within-an-iframe):

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("idName").SetAttribute("value") = "ddddd" ;
```

Edit:

Then figure out where to point your Cursor and position it using this code

```
Cursor.Position = wb.PointToScreen(new Point(X_Coord, Y_Coord));
```

Then perform a Mouse click using code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737258/1623971) by [JohnForDummies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223042/johnfordummies)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        public static void DoMouseClick()
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

You can simulate keyboard presses using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228166/1623971) by [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631823/rajesh)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

const int VK_UP = 0x26; //up key
const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;  //down key
const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;
const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
int press()
{
    //Press the key
    keybd_event((byte)VK_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can't access the html tags which in iframe tag with this code.

Comment: i added code for the mouse positioning and clicking